# Node.js - How would I set up this little service for my web app?

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, push

I'm trying to understand and experiment with **node.js** and am interested in how this would go in practice:

Let's say I have an news website with **articles that are updated all the time** by different users. When a particular article has been updated (someone edited some text) I **want it to be updated in other clients' windows** as well, **real time**.

**What would be the best structure to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket.IO: http://socket.io/ 
Faye: http://faye.jcoglan.com/